# UITextField not receiving touch event

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in a complex view hierarchy. The text field is in a UIView with label and textfield, say, labelfield.

I can type text there.

There is info button on top right corner. When tap on Info, a modal view controller is loaded. When coming back from the modal view controller, the UITextField becomes unresponsive. I cannt type anything there. The labelfiedl is drawn and shown in the screen.

Interesting thing is that, if I press the ok button, and alert is shown and then the textfield  becomes active. Also, on top of the view, there is some text with user interaction enable, if I tap and try to select the text and after that the textfield becomes active. Seems I have to do some other activity/touch on the super view, then the text field becomes active.

Why not on the first case it receive any touch event? I tried with textField.enabled, becomesFirstResponder, setNeedsDisplay in the viewDidApper method, nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try the following...

- Make sure that the super view to which the text field is added as subview large enough to contain text field(ie make sure that no part of text field is out side the superview. check this for all views).
- Make sure that there is no view above textfield.use `bringSubViewToFront:` method.
- Try to enable use interaction after a delay

Hope any of the above fix will solve your problem

Comment: The textfield is shown, and I checked (painted in color) its above all views. 
I manipulate something with delay, then it works.

Comment: I have a UITextField in a UIView, which is itself on the top of UIImageView, so I am not to get any response from UITextField, any suggestion

Comment: Check whether user interaction is enable for every view inthe hierarchy. Here in your case Imageview, View and text view.